# Q&A: Are the vectors linearly dependent on $C^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

*If anyone has a better way/see any mistake please write it down.

### Question $1_a$:

Let $z = (1-2i, 3+i)$, $w = (2-5i, 7-i)$.

Are $z,w$ linearly dependent on $C$ or $R$?

---

Comment: I don't understand the first sentence. A better way than *what*?

Comment: a better way to solve this question than what i did.

Comment: I missed the fact that you provided an answer.

Comment: The determinant is nonzero, so $z$ and $w$ are linear independent over $\Bbb C$.

Comment: how did you look at the determinant that is easier to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct, but I think that it easier to chack that $z$ and $w$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb C$ as follows:\begin{align}\text{$z$ and $w$ are linearly dependent}&\iff(\exists\lambda\in\mathbb C):w=\lambda z\\&\iff\frac{2-5i}{1-2i}=\frac{7-i}{3+i}\\&\iff(2-5i)(3+i)=(7-i)(1-2i)\end{align}and the final equality doesn't hold.

Comment: Ok thanks i learned something knew, but how did you conclude that there is not $\lambda$? it looks like you took $\lambda = 1$

Comment: Not at all:\begin{align}w=\lambda z&\iff(w_1,w_2)=(\lambda z_1,\lambda z_2)\\&\iff\frac{w_1}{z_1}=\frac{w_2}{z_2}(=\lambda).\end{align}

Comment: Understood, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking on $C$.

$a,b \in C$
$$az+bw = 0$$
$$\Downarrow$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1-2i&2-5i&|0 \\
3+i&7-i&|0
\end{bmatrix}
\xrightarrow{R_2 \leftarrow R_2 - \frac{3+i}{1-2i}R_1} \begin{bmatrix}
1-2i&2-5i&|0 \\
0&\frac{-6-2i}{1-2i}&|0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The matrix is invertible so there is only one solution to the homogenous system which is the zero vector, so $z,w$ are linear independent on $C$.

$R \subseteq C \Rightarrow \ z,w$ are linear independent on $R$ as well.